# Equivalent function for TO_CHAR (in Oracle SQL) in Hive

Tags: sql, oracle, pyspark, hive, sas

In Oracle SQL (PROC SQL in SAS), we do convert the Numeric value to a String using TO_CHAR which results in different values than the original numeric values. Reference:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm

In Oracle the input:

3630818330781419569152

outputs

3630818330781420171227

The above example is done using SAS PROC SQL

```
proc sql;
connect to oracle(..credentials..);
create table output_table as
select  myCol1 informat=$50. format=$50. , *
from    connection to oracle (
select  to_char(myCol1) myCol2
from input_table);
disconnect from oracle;
```

I am trying to find an equivalent function (TO_CHAR for Oracle SQL) in Hive which does the same.

I tried with the following which does not achieve the goal.

```
df_output = df.limit(5).withColumn("myCol2", f.col("myCol1").cast(LongType()))
```

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Presumably you meant [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm) overload instead, not the one taking a `DATETIME`. How do you *actually* invoke the function? What's the type of the input argument/column?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have added the SAS PROC SQL script which converts the input to the output.

Comment: And what's the type of `myCol1`? There is nothing in your code itself to suggest that a value is being processed, so the only real way it could change is if some sort of loss of precision is going on from storing or reading floating-point.

Comment: Hi, it is a numeric as it says within Oracle. Precision by means you are referring to the informats and formats which are in the code?. I am naive to this particular conversion, still trying to get what possible ways i could replicate in Hive.

Comment: can you please try `CAST (col as STRING)` ?